# I am facing unknown error after created build successfully and want to start app it give me unknown error

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, eas

[image: this is error when I click on http"//10.0.2.2:8081]
[image: this error show when I try to reload app from terminal]

I have expo go project and I created the build using android studio and eas build. this is come from last many day my pervious all build working fine but before some days ago any time I created new build I am facing this issue. this issue take my many days. here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "feuder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@animatereactnative/marquee": "^0.2.0",
    "@config-plugins/react-native-webrtc": "^7.0.0",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^7.8.4",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^7.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.14",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.16",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.6.3",
    "@types/react-native-calendars": "^1.1264.7",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "axios-retry": "^4.0.0",
    "country-state-city": "^3.2.1",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-constants": "^15.4.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-device": "^5.6.0",
    "expo-font": "^11.6.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.5.0",
    "expo-linking": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-screen-capture": "~5.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.53",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "process-nextick-args": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1303.0",
    "react-native-compressor": "^1.8.24",
    "react-native-country-codes-picker": "^2.3.5",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.5",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.4.7",
    "react-native-incall-manager": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.4",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-pie": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-record-screen": "^0.6.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "react-native-share": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-simple-peer": "^0.1.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-swipe-modal-up-down": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-notifications": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^118.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.4",
    "recordrtc": "^5.6.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.3",
    "yarn": "^1.22.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

this is report that give me expo go

```
{
  "appName": "Feuder",
  "timestamp": 1711080115882,
  "message": "Unknown",
  "runtimeVersion": "",
  "sdkVersion": "49.0.0",
  "appVersion": "1.0.0",
  "stack": "java.lang.Throwable\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)\n\tat expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.invokeDelegateMethod$expo_debug(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:105)\n\tat expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.getPackages(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:77)\n\tat com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:86)\n\tat expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:32)\n\tat com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)\n\tat expo.modules.devlauncher.launcher.DevLauncherNetworkInterceptor.shouldEmitEvents(DevLauncherNetworkInterceptor.kt:45)\n\tat expo.modules.devlauncher.launcher.DevLauncherNetworkInterceptor.dispatch(DevLauncherNetworkInterceptor.kt:56)\n\tat expo.modules.kotlin.devtools.ExpoRequestCdpInterceptor$dispatchEvent$1.invokeSuspend(ExpoRequestCdpInterceptor.kt:35)\n\tat kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)\n\tat kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)\n\tat kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)\n\tat kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)\n\tat kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)\n\tat kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)\n"
}
```

I try to run my project because any time I change the gradle I have to create new build using eas but if I face this issue how I can run this project. Please help me out to resolve this issue. Thank you so much in advance